# How do you close the connection when sending raw data back to the client?

Tags: .net, sockets, zeromq

I am trying to implement ZeroMQ as a Server to older clients using the .Net socket object.

In my Server I'm able to receive the bytes from the client just fine, but when I do a send, the client never seems to receive it.

My Server code:

```
var socket = context.CreateStreamSocket();
var replyMessages = socket.ReceiveMessages();
var receivedBytes = BitConverter.ToString(replyMessages.ElementAt(1));
var responseMessage = StringToByteArray("03034312");
socket.Send(responseMessage, responseMessage.Length, true);   // <-- This sends fine, but the client waits endlessly
```

And the Client Code:

```
Socket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket.Connect(ipAddress, port);

Socket.Send(data);

var replyBytes = new Byte[4];
Socket.Receive(replyBytes);  // <-- Hangs on this line
```

When I stop the server, the client immediately gets a response, which makes me think I need to disconnect the connection after the server does the socket.Send().

I must be missing something trivial, any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `socket.close()`? (or flush)

Comment: @richard, thanks, it's a good suggestion (and it does return to the client), but I have the socket.ReceiveMessages in a loop, so when it loops around the socket is closed and throws an exception.  Also, it appears that the bytes returned to the client are all 0s as well.

Comment: The error may be in the receiver. what happens if you change `replyBytes = new Byte[1]`?

Comment: @richard, same result, it hangs

Comment: Have you tried wireshark, so you can look at the data flow between the two ends? It takes a bit of getting used to but is worth the effort.